# Is $z=f(x/y), y\neq 0$ a multivariable function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Is $z=f(x/y), y\neq 0$ a multivariable function?

I was doing an exercise which asks me to find $z_x$ and $z_y$, I was unsure on how to do this, as I think that $z$ is a single variable function, is this correct?

Comment: It is a single variable function. I think the point is to apply the chain rule.

Comment: I did, but I was not sure that what I was doing was correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. $f$ is a single variable function, $z$ is a two variable function. You get, e.g. $$z_y = f^\prime(x/y) \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \frac{x}{y}$$
(which I leave to you for evaluation).

*Edit:* Read this as $z(x,y) = f(\phi(x,y))$ with $\phi(x,y) = \frac{x}{y}$

Comment: I got $-\frac {xf'}{y^2}$ I'm not sure that's correct.

Comment: Hmm, wait, how can $f$ be a single variable function and $z$ be a two variable function if they're equal?

Comment: yes, it is. If you calculate partial derivates wrt to $y$ the not on $y$ depending variable $x$ is treated like a constant.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD I added a comment to my reply to address your confusion..

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD "...wait...": $z$ is the composition of a single variable function ($f$) and a function of two variables $(x,y)\rightarrow \phi(x,y)=\frac{x}{y}$, say. The composition $f\circ \phi (x,y) = f(\phi(x,y))= f(x/y)$ is defined on pairs of numbers $(x,y), y\neq 0$, so it is a function of two variables. In your question this is obfuscated because it is written down rather sloppily as $z=f(x/y)$.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm a bit slow for this...